# MSP Nodes act for a consensus service in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

**Which component acts as a consensus service?
MSP Nodes?
Ordering Nodes?
Endorsing Nodes?
I am NOT sure what it is**

Comment: I'd start with https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/txflow.html

Answer (score 1):

Consensus means all parties agree on a particular decision. In the case of a blockchain network, members of the network arrive at a consensus on the contents of the blockchain. It’s telling that consensus is part of the ordering step of Fabric’s execute-order-validate architecture. The orderer determines which transactions to add to the blockchain and in what order.

```
The consensus is achieved at Ordering Node.
```

1) Kafka

> In Kafka, only the leader does the ordering and only the in-sync
>   replicas can be voted as the leader. This provides crash
>   fault-tolerance and finality happens in a matter of seconds. While
>   Kafka is a crash fault-tolerant, it is not Byzantine fault-tolerant,
>   which prevents the system from reaching an agreement in the case of
>   malicious or faulty nodes.

2) Raft

> In the case of RAFT, orderer itself act as a raft node, we must have
>   multiple raft node to tolerate the fault and overcome the single point of 
>   failure.

Comment: The above answer is not actually 100% correct.  While the ordering services does use a "traditional" consensus mechanism, it is just for ordering.  You should take a look at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/txflow.html

Answer (score 1):

Both peers and ordering nodes are required to achieve consensus on transactions in Fabric.

- ordering nodes are responsible for ordering transactions and batching into blocks (note that ordering nodes themselves do use a consensus mechanism in order to ensure that the ordering nodes are all in sync)
- peer nodes are responsible for executing chaincode and then validating and committing transactions to the ledger

The overall [flow](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/txflow.html) to achieve consensus on transactions at a high level is as follows:

- endorsement policy - each chaincode has an endorsement policy which is used to enforce the number of organizations whose peer(s) need to execute chaincode and sign the result.  Clients send requests to the peer(s) of the organization's required to meet the endorsement policy
- clients aggregate those responses and send to the ordering service to order and batch transactions
- ordering nodes deliver blocks to the peers or the organizations (on a per channel basis based on channel membership)
- peers then validate the transactions bu checking to see that the endorsement policy has been meet as well as checking for "double spend".  If the transactions pass this validation, they are committed and the state change is applied to the state database

The above is how consensus is achieved in Fabric